# Url path displayed twice

Tags: angular

these are my routes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', canActivate: [Auth3Guard], component: RezerwacjaListComponent},
    {path: 'reset_password/:email2/:secret2', component: ResetPasswordComponent},
];
```

Problem is: when I go to url:
http://localhost:4200/reset_password/1/2, i get the error 'Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '1/2'

but when I go to url:
http://localhost:4200/reset_password/reset_password/1/2  - (notice doubled route param)
everything works ok, i move to the right component.

The error occurs also in production environment.

Comment: Is this your root module or another module which you load lazily by `const appRoutes: [ { path: 'reset_password', loadChildren: 'pathtomodule#Module' }]` and having your above configuration in that module.

Comment: this is app module